# DIV doesn't show up and z-index has no effect either

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to create those diagonal stripe layout in CSS, like this: http://www.website-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/tdomf/355/Nike%20Bloed%20Oranje%20Art%20Challenge%202.0.png

Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/zvWRNW

It looks ok, but the problem is the "div class="blacktop" doesn't show up. I want it to overlap the gray div, and it seems z-index has no effect either even though I set position:relative to all DIVs.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div.gray, div.blackbottom {
  width: 135%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -140px;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg);
  -moz-prop: skew(-20deg, -20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-prop: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
}

div.blackbottom {
  margin-top: -100px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 200;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(17deg);
  -moz-prop: rotate(17deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(17deg);
  transform: rotate(17deg);
}

div.blacktop {
  width: 135%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray"></div>
<div class="blackbottom"></div>
<div class="blacktop"></div>
```

Comment: Your `z-index` do have effect, the rest you can see in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your first two divs are not floating or anything, they have a height and push the following div down. If you disable the `overflow:hidden` on body you'll see your black div.

Long answer short: make your blacktop `position:absolute` so that it floats above the background divs.

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOdJQr

HTML:

```
<div class="gray"></div>
<div class="blackbottom"></div>
<div class="blacktop"></div>
```

CSS

```
@mixin prefix ($prop, $val)
{
  -webkit-#{$prop}: #{$val};
  -moz-#{prop}: #{$val};
  -ms-#{$prop}: #{$val};
  #{$prop}: #{$val};
}

body
{
  overflow:hidden;
}

div
{
  position:relative;
}

div.gray
{
  width:135%;
  height:450px;
  background-color:gray;
  margin:-10px 0 0 -140px;
  z-index:100;
  @include prefix(transform, skew(-20deg,-20deg));
  @include prefix(transform, rotate(8deg));
}

div.blackbottom
{
  @extend div.gray;

  margin-top:-100px;
  background-color:white;
  z-index:200;
  @include prefix(transform, rotate(17deg));
}

div.blacktop
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width:135%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:black;
  z-index:300;
}
```

Comment: Right. I removed that sentence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I added the same shared settings to `.blacktop` as the other 2 div's have, so if you update your css like this it shows.

```
div.blacktop
{
  @extend div.gray;

  top: -500px;
  width:135%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:black;
  z-index:300;
  @include prefix(transform, rotate(17deg));
}
```

And here as a snippet

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div.gray, div.blackbottom, div.blacktop {
  width: 135%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -140px;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg);
  -moz-prop: skew(-20deg, -20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg, -20deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-prop: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
}

div.blackbottom {
  margin-top: -100px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 200;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(17deg);
  -moz-prop: rotate(17deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(17deg);
  transform: rotate(17deg);
}

div.blacktop {
  top: -500px;
  width: 135%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 300;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(17deg);
  -moz-prop: rotate(17deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(17deg);
  transform: rotate(17deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="gray"></div>
<div class="blackbottom"></div>
<div class="blacktop"></div>
```

Comment: I think the OP intended the black box to not be rotated. Or at least the only black box in the screenshot isn't.

Comment: Maybe so, then he just take out that line from my sample.